# Complex JPQL query using the criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I am trying to write the following query using jpa criteria api

```
Select pk from DIFF_GLOBALID g INNER JOIN DIFF_CDO c ON c.CDO_PK = g.CLASS_FK
where g.LOCAL_ID = :localId AND c.QUALIFIED_NAME = :qualifiedName
```

I tried to write it but not sure if this is right and also not sure how to write where clause now

```
final CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<CdoModel> from = cq.from(CdoModel.class);
final Join<CdoModel, GlobalIdModel> join = from.join("classfk");
cq.select(join.get("pk"));


@Entity
@Table(name = "DIFF_CDO")
public class CdoModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CDO_PK")
    private final long pk;

    @Column(name = "QUALIFIED_NAME")
    private String qualifiedName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DIFF_GLOBALID")
public class GlobalIdModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GLOBALID_PK")
    private final long pk;

    @Column(name = "CLASS_FK")
    private long classfk;

    @Column(name = "LOCAL_ID")
    private String localid;

    @Column(name = "FRAGMENT")
    private String fragment;

    @Column(name = "OWNER_ID_FK")
    private long owneridfk;
}
```

Comment: so what have you tried for the WHERE clause? All Criteria tutorials tell you how to start. For example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html   and nobody can help without seeing classes since they don't know what the fields are called. Your original "JPL" (JPQL perhaps) is not JPQL ... unless you really have fields called "LOCAL_ID", "QUALIFIED_NAME", etc (this is fields NOT columns). And what is createQuery(Long) ??!! The candidate is supposed to be some entity.

Comment: Where is your JPQL? Do you mean "using the criteria API" rather than "using JPQL"? Why don't you actually use JPQL?

Comment: i updated the issue with my entities. i know how to write where clause for single entity but now there is a join now so i am stuck somehow. createQuery(Long) is because i want to just get the PK which is Long.

Comment: you can't join on something that is NOT a relation ("classfk"). Your JPQL is wrong (use fields not columns).